# How to calculate running mean traffic for last minute

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures

I have a python server that accepts time series data. Now I need to calculate the average traffic for the last minute, output like 90 samples/minute. I'm currently using a python list to hold all time stamps and use a pretty awful way(in my opinion) to calculate this. The code roughly looks like this:

```
class TrafficCalculator(object):
    timestamps = []

    def run():
        while True:
            # this gets one record of traffic
            data = self.accept_data()
            # get record's timestamp
            timestamp = data.timestamp
            # add to list
            self.timestamps.append(timestamp)
            # get the time one minute ago
            minute_ago = timestamp - datetime.timedelta(minutes=1)
            # find out the first index of the timestamp in the past that's within 1 minute
            for i, t in enumerate(self.timestamp):
                if t > minute_ago:
                    break
            # see how many records are within last minute
            result = len(self.timestamp[i:])
            # throw away the earlier data
            self.timestamp = self.timestamp[i:]
```

As you can see, I have to do this for every record, if my traffic gets intense, the performance is miserable.

Is there a better data structure or algorithm I can use to make this more performant? Even further, how do I write a test to verify my algorithm? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use something like [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html)?

Comment: Have you tried just ticking up an int every time the function is hit and clear that once a minute? To test your class all you have to do is spin up a script that hammers self.accept_data() with random data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Queue to hold `<traffic, timestamp>` pair. Here `timestamp` is the time it has been pushed on Queue(arrives from server). Track the `sum` of the traffics of Queue. When a new traffic arrives and the difference between its timestamp and Queue's front element's timestamp more than 1 minute, pop front from Queue. And subtract the poped traffic value from sum. Push the new traffic into queue and add to sum.

This way, your queue is working as a window frame to hold the 1 minute traffic all the time. And you are tracking the sum and you know the Queue size, so you can calculate the average.

The space complexity is `O(maximum traffic can be arrived within 1 minute)`. Time complexity is `O(1)` for getting average at any time.

This is a very conventional algorithm for *Query on any running stream of data in constant time complexity*.

Note: Unfortunately I don't know Python. Otherwise I would put the implementation.

Comment: Thanks, you don't know python but I know programming so it's OK. I kinda feel bad at the same time because it's so obvious.

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes we miss very obvious things :)

Answer (score 1):

You could be able to achieve it with something like this:

- define a vector (or a list) `data` of length 90 (samples/min.)
- have a pointer `p=0`
- have a `sum` variable (unintialized yet)

Fill in the vector with the 90 first samples; compute the sum and put in in the variable `sum`.

Then:

- substract `data[p]` from `sum` (remove oldest sample from the sum)
- read next sample and put it in the vector at location `p`
  (thus erasing the oldest data) ;
- add new `data[p]` to the `sum` (current sum)
- increment pointer `p` by 1 ; if `p`>=90, then `p`=0 again
  (`p` points to the oldest available data)
- current mean is `sum/90`

etc.